# Visual Studio Code. why are the window control buttons over the menu bar on the left side?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was working on the visual studio application.
And suddenly, my window control buttons hopped to the left side of the main menu navbar,
hiding the buttons File & Edit.

Does anyone know how to re-placing the windows control buttons back to the right side of the navbar?

[image: windows overlay control on the left side]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In vscode v1.71.2 the `window.experimental.windowControlsOverlay.enabled` setting has been disabled by default.

---

This bug was released in vscode v1.71.  It may be related to using RTL languages.  I would assume this will be fixed in a point release.

Try disabling this setting:

`window.experimental.windowControlsOverlay.enabled`

from [windows default close button location moved on its own when updating to v1.71.0][1]

Comment: It should be noted that VSCode no longer understands this command

Comment: @ElectricCoffee That is a setting, not a command.  And it is still in vscode as of v1.77.3.