# How to move windows10 window control button to the right?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

After last update of Vscode the window control button are hiding the Vscode menu. See top left (in white border) in the image below.
I am running Windows10 Pro.

Is there a way to move those buttons to the top-right corner?

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73595132/836330 and a possible fix there.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [suggested link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73595132/836330) by @Mark, the issue is of Vscode integration into Windows 10.

I spent some time looking how to perform the change.

So:

1. Open (hidden) File menu using ATL-F
2. Select Preferences-> setting
3. Serach for `window.experimental.windowControlsOverlay.enabled`
4. Option should not be checked

See the screenshot below: (note: vscode will request & should restart)
[image]